# NodeJS HTTP Server and Console.log

Tags: node.js, http, logging

I have a simple HTTP server

```
require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World!');

    console.log('Got a request');   
}).listen(4000);
```

However, when I run it 'Got a request' is written 3 times in the console. Any idea why?

Comment: Check the network tab in your browsers console, you should see every request between the client and the server. Like Sachacr said one would be favicon

Answer (score 2):

It's maybe your browser who try to get your favicon

You can confirm this by using : `console.log('Got a request : ' + req.url);`

Comment: Thanks - that was it indeed (apologies for the late reply).